# How to inspect 'class not found' problems in layout files from Android Studio during developing?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio, lint, code-inspection

After refactoring my project files(including delete files, moving files etc.), the result app have crashed sometimes because of `'java.lang.ClassNotFoundException'` about some custom widget. 
[Crash Message: 'class not found during layout inflating...' from logcat screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uLfUS.png)

I know that this is about layout file inflating error and I have solved it. 
Some custom widget Class file is package changed. Java source file can find the unresolved symbol problem and quickfixes it through the Lint tool, but layout files not. Additionally, I can not find a way to inspect the similar problem in layout files with Android Studio Lint tool. 
[Can not found some relevant inspection items to enable in Android Studio.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ld7bd.png)

It's really a bad idea to solve one problem item after one crash. So I need a way to inspect the problems in layout files before running the app :)

Comment: Please inline your error message instead of linking to them.

Comment: check the class name in the xml.

Comment: @msparer Thank you for your advice, this is my first question:)

Comment: @DevendraSingh I can find and solve the problem with the Log information after crash. But how can I inspect similar problems may existing else where through Tool like Lint etc. I can not find relevant items in Inspections Profile settings in Android Studio.